# Loading Jquery Tooltip For Dynamicaly loaded content

Tags: jquery

I would like to get Jquery tooltip shown when hovered on anchor tag which id dynamically loaded.

**Using Jquery Cluetip**

Comment: i am out of ideas as of now :(

Comment: I recommend using qTip2, has a simple documentation, and you can download content dynamically via ajax: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/plugins/ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try Some thing like this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            loadtip();
        });


function loadtip() {
            $('a.tips').cluetip({
            showTitle: true ,
            arrows: true              
          });
        }
```

**after loading your dynamic content call this function again:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            loadtip();
        });
```